# how to extract a portion of text from a file between matched conditions

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a file as below.

```
~PAR1~
This is Par1 line 1
This is Par1 line 2

Par Finished

~PAR2~
This is Par2 line 1
This is Par2 line 2

Par Finished
```

If I pass `PAR1`, I should get all lines between `PAR1` and `Par Finished` line. How can I get it? I was looking into `awk` and `sed` and couldn't find any options.

Answer (score 14):

If you want the header and footer line then it's pretty simple with `sed`
eg

```
sed -n "/^~PAR1~$/,/Par Finished/p"
```

This is simple to use with a variable

```
START=PAR1
sed -n "/^~$START~$/,/Par Finished/p"
```

We can also make the last line to be a variable

```
START=PAR1
END="Par Finished"
sed -n "/^~$START~$/,/$END/p"
```

The result looks like:

```
~PAR1~
This is Par1 line 1
This is Par1 line 2

Par Finished
```

Now if you don't want the start/end lines and you don't want the blank line then it's a little more complicated.

There may be better ways, but this works for me:

```
sed -n "/^~$START~$/,/$END/ { /^~$START~$/d ; /$END/d ; /^$/d ; p }"
```

The result of this is

```
This is Par1 line 1
This is Par1 line 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `Par Finished` line (with optional trailing blank lines) as record separator (and then replace it to complete the record)

```
awk -vRS='\nPar Finished\n*' -vp='PAR1' '$0 ~ p {print $0,"\nPar Finished"}' parfile
~PAR1~
This is Par1 line 1
This is Par1 line 2

Par Finished
```

If you have `GNU` awk, you can recover the record separator with the special variable `RT` (stripping the extra newlines if you wish)

```
gawk -vRS='\nPar Finished\n*' -vp='PAR1' '$0 ~ p {sub("\n*$", "", RT); print $0,RT}' parfile
~PAR1~
This is Par1 line 1
This is Par1 line 2

Par Finished
```

Of course if you don't need to pass a *variable* `Par1` you use a simple regex range

```
awk '/PAR1/,/Par Finished/' parfile
~PAR1~
This is Par1 line 1
This is Par1 line 2

Par Finished
```

Answer (score 2):

With `grep` and `pcre` for small enough file input

```
$ s="PAR1"

$ grep -oPz "(?s)[^\n]*${s}.*?\n.*?Par Finished.*?\n" ip.txt 
~PAR1~
This is Par1 line 1
This is Par1 line 2

Par Finished
```

To get lines between the pattern:

```
$ grep -oPz "(?s)${s}.*?\n\K.*?(?=Par Finished)" ip.txt 
This is Par1 line 1
This is Par1 line 2
```

Changing variable to `PAR2`

```
$ s="PAR2"
$ grep -oPz "(?s)${s}.*?\n\K.*?(?=Par Finished)" ip.txt 
This is Par2 line 1
This is Par2 line 2
```

**Reference:** [Regex (grep) for multi-line search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717772/regex-grep-for-multi-line-search-needed)